# How can I change GWT's widget CSS values?

Tags: java, css, gwt

Basically, I like default theme widgets. However, I need to change font size on **DecoratedStackPanel** widget.

I think it should be possible with something like this:

```
decoratedStackPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("fontSize", "12pt");
```

However, "fontSize" is not valid name for property and I didn't find way **how to get all element's properties.** Therefore, I don't know correct property name.

Any ideas?

Please, don't post about inheriting widget or writing custom CSS. I like default one but the font size. This should be possible afaik.

Comment: It really wouldn't be all that difficult to set the CSS class to a specific class and then writing CSS to style it, I'm not sure why you're resistant to writing CSS when it's better to have this in CSS than in code.

Comment: It's ok to write CSS for little widget, but this one is rather complex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fontSize is correct, the best way to use is as follows:

```
decoratedStackPanel.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(12, Unit.PT);
```

But i'm not sure this will result in what you want. it sets the font size on the whole panel, and if another font size is set on a child element that one will be used in that element. In that case a css entry for the specific element would be better. For example:

```
.gwt-DecoratedStackPanel .gwt-StackPanelItem {
   font-size:12pt !important;
}
```

(!important will force to use this specific font-size setting, and should only be used if you want to make sure this font-size is used. First test without).

Comment: another problem ... while the size works, why doesn't this? font-weight: normal !important; adding into same rule?

Comment: It might be a sub element which contains the actual text contains a font-weight, but not the font-size. To check use for example chrome browser inspect element to see which properties are set. There are some font-weight bold in the gwt styles, so it might be the cause. Just set them on the right css element with important should fix this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use DOM class to set style attributes..

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(decoratedStackPanel.getElement(), "fontSize", "12pt");
```

Comment: I don't know if "fontSize" is valid name ... that's what I am asking

Comment: sorry, it should be font-size and I think 12pt is not valid value for font size. It can be , small,x-small,xx-small, or 12px etc... check http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font-size.asp

Comment: fontSize is correct, you should be using the javascript attributes not the css attribute of font-size.  The following site contains a complete reference, however fontSize is not listed as confirmed to work by the author, however the gwt style source uses fontSize.  http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html

Answer (score 1):

fontSize would be translated to font-size